# How to get matching group value from Regular Expression

Tags: java, regex

I have a following Java code. If regular expression matches from multiple group then I want only the value of matching group.

```
final String regex = "^(\\d{1,2}-\\d{1,2}-\\d{4})|(\\d{4}-\\d{1,2}-\\d{1,2})$";
final Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(regex);
final Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher("1988-02-02");
if (matcher.find()) {
    // I want matching group value. In this case (\\d{4}-\\d{1,2}-\\d{1,2})
}
```

Can we have any way to achieve this?

Comment: So `return matcher.group(1) != null ? matcher.group(1) : matcher.group(2);`?

Comment: @ctwheels, I have multiple groups and want exact matching group from them. So ternary operator will not work in that case.

Comment: Then it's not clear what you want.

Comment: Do you want a [branch reset](https://www.regular-expressions.info/branchreset.html) group, (?|...|...) to only get one group instead of multiple ones? Not in Java.

Answer (score 0):

Put the two groups inside a larger group so both matches are contained with the same set of parentheses.

```
final String regex = "^((\\d{1,2}-\\d{1,2}-\\d{4})|(\\d{4}-\\d{1,2}-\\d{1,2}))$";
final Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(regex);
final Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher("1988-02-02");
if (matcher.find()) {
    String match = matcher.group(1);
    ...
}
```

You can remove the inner sets of parentheses if you don't need them.

```
final String regex = "^(\\d{1,2}-\\d{1,2}-\\d{4}|\\d{4}-\\d{1,2}-\\d{1,2})$";
```

Comment: I have multiple groups and want exact matching group from them. So combining groups will not work.